# How to Save OpenGL Viewport Animation in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, opengl, file-browser

I am able to create the viewport animation, and then play it back from the render menu, but there doesn't appear to be any option to save it. When I render from the camera I have, it saves to the path specified in the render options in the properties panel. However, viewport animations don't show up there. Very confused as to where that file is going to allow playback from the render menu at the top of the viewport.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Both viewport render options save to the path specified in the *Output* tab in the *Output* panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify where the file is gonna be saved before you render it from the viewport! Otherwise it doesn't work, I had the same issue.

Comment: But how? What is the button/menu I need to click

Comment: @Ben Winding go to Properties->Output Properties->Output and define a folder

Answer (score 0):

just like normal  animation  select the output file and hit render 
and u will find the animation there its being playing from the output file